# Reference blaze helper function in second helper

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I would like to access blaze helper functions within a second helper function. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

```
Template.example.helpers({
  functionOne: function (){
    return { min: salMin, max: salMax, sal: salary };
  },
  functionTwo: function (){
    var one = functionOne.min;
    var two = functionOne.max;

    return one - two;
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML CODE: you can pass the returned values from helper `functionOne` to `functionTwo`

```
{{#with functionOne}}
    {{functionTwo min max}}
{{/with}}
```

Helper Code:

```
Template.example.helpers({
    functionOne: function (){
        var salMin = 20;
        var salMax = 100;
        var salary = 90;

        return { min: salMin, max: salMax, sal: salary };
    },
    functionTwo: function (min, max){
        return min - max;
    },
});
```